# How can I get suggestions (registerCompletionItemProvider) to show between curly braces in for Markdown in Monaco?

Tags: monaco-editor

When I create a completion item provider in Monaco for Markdown I'm unable to create suggestions for text between curly braces {}

i.e. `{ typing in here won't launch the suggestions widget }`

I get that braces are reserved keywords in Markdown and are auto-closed in Monaco by default. Even if auto closing is off, once there is a matching ending curly brace autocomplete won't work.

Is there an option to make this work? Or will I have to make a new language that is basically a copy of Markdown that doesn't register curly braces as a bracket?

Here's a monaco editor playground snippet that shows this issue

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('markdown', {
    provideCompletionItems: function() {
        return {
            suggestions: [
                {
                    label: "random_number",
                    insertText: "random_number"
                },
                {
                    label: "now",
                    insertText: "now"
                },
                {
                    label: "today",
                    insertText: "today"
                },
            ]
        };
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "# hello.\n{autocomplete doesn't work between braces: }\nbut it works outside: ",
    language: "markdown"
});
```

### Edit

Bit more info: it's possible the reason suggestions aren't launching is that Markdown treats anything between curly braces { } as a token and colors it.

https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-languages/blob/618f2cff2d8e72f04fe9d63085a0c5118b80e8a0/src/markdown/markdown.ts#L143

Not clear why this is necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine with your originally-posted code. Perhaps you are expecting it to auto-suggest based on the current word, if one were to break up the text within the curly braces into separate words? Keep in mind that `{...}` is a single token, so autocomplete will try to match the prefix consisting of all of the text starting with the first char after the bracket until the cursor position-- i.e. if the text is `{hello there how are you}` and the cursor position is 12 (after "there"), the prefix to match to is "hello there" and not just "there":

So for example:
[image]

Which is from your original code, with one additional suggestion:

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('markdown', {
    provideCompletionItems: function() {
        return {
            suggestions: [
                {
                    label: "random_number",
                    insertText: "random_number"
                },
                {
                    label: "now",
                    insertText: "now"
                },
                {
                    label: "today",
                    insertText: "today"
                },
                {
                    label: "autocomplete does work fine between braces",
                    insertText: "autocomplete does work fine between braces"
                },
            ]
        };
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "# hello.\n{autocomplete doesn't work between braces: }\nbut it works outside: ",
    language: "markdown"
});
```